# How to create "blank" yaml-file for Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

My directory structure contains multiple docker-compose.yaml files, each on it's own directory. All of them are running with one bash-script.

If there is some directories (and configuration), which I do not want to run, how to create "empty" docker-compose.yaml-file to run? Empty file is not accepted

```
ERROR: Top level object in './docker-compose.yaml' needs to be an object not '<class 'NoneType'>'.
```

Comment: Try `{}`, which evaluates to an empty YAML mapping.

Comment: yeps, seems to help. I get some warning, but better than error

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `version` number:

```
version: "3"
```